# Is there a way to improve the performance of this fractal calculation algorithm?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, fractals

Yesterday I came across the new 3Blue1Brown video about Newton's fractal and I was really mesmerized by his live representation of the fractal. (Here's the video link for anybody interested, it's at 13:40: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RdOwhmqP5s)

I wanted to have a go at it myself and tried to code it in python (I think he uses python too).

I spent a few hours trying to improve my naive implementation and got to a point where I just don't know how could I make it faster.

The code looks like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from time import time


def print_fractal(state):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    gs = GridSpec(1, 1)
    axs = [fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])]
    fig.tight_layout(pad=5)
    axs[0].matshow(state)
    axs[0].set_xticks([])
    axs[0].set_yticks([])
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


def get_function_value(z):
    return z**5 + z**2 - z + 1


def get_function_derivative_value(z):
    return 5*z**4 + 2*z - 1


def check_distance(state, roots):
    roots2 = np.zeros((roots.shape[0], state.shape[0], state.shape[1]), dtype=complex)
    for r in range(roots.shape[0]):
        roots2[r] = np.full((state.shape[0], state.shape[1]), roots[r])
    dist_2 = np.abs((roots2 - state))
    original_state = np.argmin(dist_2, axis=0) + 1
    return original_state


def static():
    time_start = time()
    s = 4
    c = [0, 0]
    n = 800
    polynomial = [1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1]
    roots = np.roots(polynomial)
    state = np.transpose((np.linspace(c[0] - s/2, c[0] + s/2, n)[:, None] + 1j*np.linspace(c[1] - s/2, c[1] + s/2, n)))
    n_steps = 15
    time_setup = time()
    for _ in range(n_steps):
        state -= (get_function_value(state) / get_function_derivative_value(state))
    time_evolution = time()
    original_state = check_distance(state, roots)
    time_check = time()
    print_fractal(original_state)
    print("{0:<40}".format("Time to setup the initial configuration:"), "{:20.3f}".format(time_setup - time_start))
    print("{0:<40}".format("Time to evolve the state:"), "{:20.3f}".format(time_evolution - time_setup))
    print("{0:<40}".format("Time to check the closest roots:"), "{:20.3f}".format(time_check - time_evolution))
```

An average output looks like this:

Time to setup the initial configuration:                0.004

Time to evolve the state:                               0.796

Time to check the closest roots:                        0.094

It's clear that it's the evolution part that bottlenecks the process. It's not "slow", but I think it's not enough to render something live like in the video. I already did what I could by using numpy vectors and avoiding loops but I guess it's not enough.
What other tricks could be applied here?

Note: I tried using numpy.polynomials.Polynomial class to evaluate the function, but it was slower than this version.

Comment: 3B1B has [his library](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) available on github. You can also try using that, not sure if it would help with the performance though

Comment: Did you consider GPU acceleration via PyOpenCL? You would need to know C++, but the PyOpenCL documentation provides a very good starting example: https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/#codecell0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I got an improvement (~40% faster) by using single complex (`np.complex64`) precision.

```
(...)
state = np.transpose((np.linspace(c[0] - s/2, c[0] + s/2, n)[:, None] 
                      + 1j*np.linspace(c[1] - s/2, c[1] + s/2, n)))
state = state.astype(np.complex64)
(...)
```

2. 3Blue1Brown added this link in the description: https://codepen.io/mherreshoff/pen/RwZPazd
   You can take a look how it was done there (sidenote: author of this pen used single precision as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in range(n_steps):
    state -= (get_function_value(state) / get_function_derivative_value(state))
```

If you have enough memory, you can try to vectorize this loop and store each iteration steps with a matrix computation.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Since each following step depends on the previous one, how can that operation be vectorized?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do this loop for every point in the plane? Then you can vectorize over those.

Answer (score 0):

Try pypy3, numba or cython.

Pypy3 is a fast cpython replacement.  For pure python code, this can be dramatically faster.

Numba's nopython mode can dramatically speed up math in cpython.  It doesn't do much more than math though.

Cython is a python dialect that transpiles to c, and allows you to mix cpython and c types.  The more c types you use, the better (usually).  Check out yhe cython -a opti9n.